# Amending this C# code to use a different calling method

Tags: c#

I am working on a C# project that tries to load a specific dll (IPDll) from sources **other than** resources from ResourceManager. This is my main:

```
public static int Main()
{
    try
    {
        return PythonOps.InitializeModuleEx(Assembly.Load((byte[])new ResourceManager("IPDll", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()).GetObject("IPDll.wp.dll")), "__main__", (string[])null, false, (Dictionary<string, object>)null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.Message;
        Console.WriteLine("Error occurred: {0}", message);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I was thinking about providing base64 input of IPDll but I am struggling to construct my code I have found this:

```
Reflect.Assembly.Load(Convert.FromBase64String(EncodedAssembly));
```

Am I trying to do the impossible or is there a way to actually do it ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine, and this one looks pretty bad. I am not even certain if that is the case of exception that should be caught. It looks to much like a Fatal Exception for me. Here are two articles on the mater that I do link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher thanks for your answer. I actually have a different idea. The file inside IPDll.resources, IPDll.wp.dll has an entry point that is being called by this application. Would you possibly know how to call it on its own ?

Comment: Usually there is only one entry point, and that is Main(). That name is pretty old, going all the way back to C. And in rough terms, both .NET/MSIL .exe and Java Programms are little more then DLL's with a Manifest, mentioning the right class and it's entry point.